# Add 0 into array_agg if there is no matching data

Tags: postgresql

I wrote this view, and it is selecting almost everything I want, but I do not get results for all: `project_keywords`(which `has_many project_report(keyword_id, project_id)`)

So a `project_keyword` has a data saved into `project_report and the data is stored into position column` but there are times when there is no data saved for a `project_keyword`.

When there is no data saved, I would like to add `0` into array_agg(pr.position).

```
 SELECT  
  k.name, 
  pr.project_id,
  array_agg(distinct pr.position) as pr_position,
  date(pr.created_at)
FROM 
  project_keywords pk
INNER JOIN keywords k on pk.keyword_id = k.id
INNER JOIN project_reports pr USING (project_id, keyword_id)
WHERE 
  date(pr.created_at) = '2014-03-27' AND pr.project_id = 2
GROUP BY k.name, pr.project_id, date(pr.created_at);
```

Also how can return results where array_agg(distinct pr.position) SIZE(no of elements) is > 1

Edit:

```
SELECT  
  k.name, 
  pr.project_id,
  COALESCE(array_agg(DISTINCT pr.position), '{0}'::integer[]),
  date(pr.created_at)
FROM 
  project_keywords pk
INNER JOIN keywords k on pk.keyword_id = k.id
INNER JOIN project_reports pr USING (project_id, keyword_id)
WHERE 
  date(pr.created_at) = '2014-03-27' AND pr.project_id = 2
GROUP BY k.name, pr.project_id, date(pr.created_at)
HAVING array_length(COALESCE(array_agg(DISTINCT pr.position), '{0}'::integer[]), 1) > 1;
```

This query is returning all the project_keywords which have project_reports row's, but they are not returning `0` for project_keywords which do not have associated rows in project_reports.

Comment: Maybe add a case when end statement in the array_agg() function? Some thing like `array_agg(case when pr.position is not null then distinct pr.position else 0 end)`

Comment: I tried that, but is not working.

Comment: Please define: `but there are times when there is no data saved for a project_keyword` What do you safe **exactly**? NULL? An empty string? No row? Table definitions or even a test case (do you know [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4d90d/3)?) would be swell for such a question: we could see `NOT NULL` or FK constraints, etc. and wouldn't have to do all the guesswork for you. The relevant parts of what `\d tbl` gives you in [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html).

Answer (score 3):

For the first point, you can try this:

```
COALESCE(array_agg(DISTINCT pr.position), '{0}'::integer[])
```

The same can be achieved by a `CASE`, too:

```
CASE WHEN array_agg(id) IS NULL
     THEN '{0}'::integer[] 
     ELSE array_agg(id) END
```

The second problem can be handled by a [`HAVING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-HAVING) cause:

```
...
GROUP BY ...
HAVING array_length(COALESCE(array_agg(DISTINCT pr.position), '{0}'::integer[]), 1) > 1;
```

Comment: it still doesn't return 0, if there is project_report record associated with project_keywords

Comment: @user36209 What _does_ it return then?

Comment: If add a condition to return only results for a project_keywords which I know that it doesn't have any row in project_report, the return is empty

Comment: @user36209 could you show that query please?

Comment: please check my post, under Edit.